# How to access Raspberry Pi UV4L Streaming server from outside ip without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, uv4l

## Expectation

1. Through a web browser, access should be made to my Raspberry Pi server that is not on the same Wi-Fi with the web browser.
2. I need to make my Raspberry Pi portable, so I don't know which Wi-Fi or IP address that my rasp-pi will connect. So, port forwarding is may not be my answer.

## Problem

When I was developing with Arduino and ESP8266, I could simply access them with the MQTT protocol because the size of data of communication was so small.

But my Raspberry Pi's Server is a 'UV4L Streaming WebSocket Server' that is handling video/audio data so the size of data of communication may be so large. That's why I think I can't use MQTT.

So I'm in situation that can't use port forwarding and MQTT to access the Raspberry Pi's Server from outside my network.

Is there way to solve my problem?

I'm a newbie developer, so there may be something I'm not quite sure about.
If it is, welcoming for pointing out, blaming.

Comment: Not sure to understand your expectations .. you wanna get connected to your rapsberry PI out of your LAN and get streaming video from its uv4l server ? a kind of spy cam ?

Comment: and trying to stream video using a message brooker like MQTT is a joke no ? ^^

Comment: You are talking about `port forwarding`. So it seems you have a private network with a NATed router, right? Within this private network you have two or more wifi networks? Your raspi should be able to change these networks? Or should it also be reachable outside your private network? Please edit your question to clarify this.